# How to fix argument not optional while calling a public function error

Tags: function, arguments

I need to convert a European date which is day/month/year to month/day/year.  I've created a public function that I was thinking would easily check the date format to make sure it is correct and then just call it in the many modules. I'm trying to test it below:

```vb
Public vReviewDate As String
Public vConvDate As String

Public Function ConvertDate(vReviewDate) As String
    ConvertDate = Month(vReviewDate) & "/" & Day(vReviewDate) & "/" & Year(vReviewDate)
End Function

Sub test()
   vReviewDate = CStr(Cells(1, 16))
   'call Function ConvertDate
   Set vConvDate = ConvertDate
   'call Function in msgbox
   MsgBox Prompt:="The date is now " & vConvDate
End Sub
```

Each time I go to test it I'm getting an "Argument not optional".

I've tried declaring public variables, changing from string to date.  I can't get it to call the Function ConvertDate(vReviewDate).  I need to get the function ConvertDate(vReviewDate) to call from within the sub.

Comment: Let me guess, Visual Basic?? Always mention your programming language and add appropriate language tag to your question so that the people who know about it can find it and have their attention attracted here.

Comment: Did you check [Argument not optional (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/argument-not-optional)? Other pages that your search engine might find for you?

Comment: Set vConvDate = ConvertDate(vReviewDate)  'pass a parameter to ConvertDate